# Creating a constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraint, ssrs, unique-constraint

I created a report that records entries
from a table which has 4 columns

```
1 Shipper ID 
2 SHipper Reference
3 loading
4 Completion
```

My primary keys are columns 1 and 2 there are no foriegn keys, columns 3 and 4 are mandatory fileds 
with a yes or no value constraint

what I want is to create a constraint that doesnt allow the user to pick these two fields (completeion and loading) as N in the same time but they can be both Y at the same time

what is the code for that constraint?

this code was my best shot

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
ADD CONSTRAINT Double_constraint check (Completion!='N' and Loading!='N')
```

but this one wont allow anything but completion to be Y and Loading to be N

Comment: `check (not (Completion = 'N' and Loading = 'N'))`  Or simply change your `and` to `or`: `check (Completion <> 'N' OR Loading <> 'N')`

Comment: @ypercube thank you so much it worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably be better off making this a `bit` field with `NOT NULL` or otherwise you also need to validate that only the strings `'Y'` and `'N'` were entered.

With the bit column arrangement the check constraint would be

```
CHECK (1 IN (Completion, Loading))
```

Otherwise with `char(1)` the check constraint could be

```
CHECK ('Y' IN (Completion, Loading))
```

but you'd need two additional column level constraints ensuring `Completion IN ('N','Y')` and similar for `Loading`.